# Присвоить значения свойствам объекта, которые получены в результате SQL запроса, заранее не зная к какому классом относится объект

Tags: c#, sql, .net, рефлексия

Есть функция:

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll()
{
    List<TEntity> result = new List<TEntity>();
    using (IDbCommand command = Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandText = QueriesBuilder.GetAllQuery;
            Connection.Open();
            using (IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var entity = Activator.CreateInstance(RepositoryInfo.TypeOfEntity);

                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (var columnName in RepositoryInfo.ColumnsInDbNames)
                    {
                        object value = reader.GetValue(i++);
                        PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
                        RepositoryInfo.PropertiesInfo.TryGetValue(columnName, out propertyInfo);
                        //Тут нужно засунуть value в нужное свойство entity

                    }
                    result.Add((TEntity)entity);
                }
            }
            Connection.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Необходимо заполнить лист `result` данными, полученными в результате запроса.
Если объект `TEntity` выглядит так:

```
[Table("Users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

То Sql запрос к базе данных будет выглядеть так:

```
SELECT [Id], [Name], [Age] FROM [Users];
```

Таблицы в базе данных всегда соответствует `TEntity`

В классе, в котором находится код функции, есть лист `List<string> ColumnsInDbNames`, которых хранит имена столбцов строго в той последовательности, в которой они перечисляются в `SELECT` запросе.

Также в классе есть словарь `Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo> PropertiesInfo`, в котором хранится информация о свойствах объекта, полученная при помощи `Type.GetProperties()`. Ключом словаря является имя столбца в базе данных, которому соответствует свойство объекта.

**Как мне присвоить полученные от IDataReader значения в необходимые свойства объекта?**

Comment: У вас с чем именно сложность? Найти свойство класса по имени столбца, или найти столбец по имени свойства? Или у вас сложность с преобразованием типа данных?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. Получайте данные,  создавайте объекты ручками или пользуйте простые ORM типа Dapper https://www.tritac.com/blog/dappernet-by-example/

Comment: Реализуйте цикл обхода столбцов - а там если будут сложности - спрашивайте.

Comment: @tym32167 нельзя ручками или использовать Dapper, я пытаюсь реализовать репозиторий без ORM

Comment: @mirypoko ручками - это и есть без ORM. Если вам надо из строки со столбцами создать экземпляр типа, который указан в генерик параметре - то пользуйте рефлексию (правда скорость работы будет небольшая)

Comment: @nick_n_a добавил цикл обхода столбцов

Comment: В чём дальше сложность? `if (trygetvalue()) propertyInfo.SetValue`

Comment: @nick_n_a пожалуйста, приведите пример использования этой функции

Comment: Для вас `propertyInfo.SetValue(entity , reader[i-1],null)`

Comment: @nick_n_a заработало так propertyInfo.SetValue(entity, value, null);. Ответе пожалуйста на вопрос, чтобы я мог выбрать ответ.

Comment: Автор, если ты не хочешь писать метод чтения для каждого объекта, я настоятельно рекомендую скомпилировать лямбда-сеттеры на основе Expression (проще) или IL (лучше), вместо того, что бы использовать Reflection. Это очень медленно и дорого.

Comment: @LunarWhisper можете скинуть ссылки на материалы, в которых рассказывается как подобное делать? Или может у вас пример есть

Comment: @mirypoko красивой статьи на русском под рукой на нашёл, вот старенькая с хабра: https://habrahabr.ru/post/83169/